# How to mock a Class like this in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to mock a method in the class

```
public class Test<T> where T : class
{
   public string GetData()
       return "Test" 
   }
}
```

How to mock the `GetData` class by using FakeItEasy? When I try to return a value using FakeITEasy it given me an message saying parameterless constructor

```
An example


  var FakeTest = A.Fake<Test<DocumentTest>>();
 A.CallTo(() => FakeTest.GetByIdAsync("Site"(A<string>.Ignored))).MustHaveHappened();
```

Comment: Show what you have tried when using `FakeItEasy` and the error. We can't guess..

Comment: Going from the partial of the error message you  mentioned. Does you mock class have a parameterless constructor? If not you need one.

Answer (score 1):

To fix a missing parameterless constructor just add

`public Test() {}`

to your class shown. That allows a mocking framework to new up an instance of the class and then set properties as needed.